# Inconsistent behavior of Cmake on a library imported by fetchcontent: Inability to find the header file

Tags: c++, json, windows, cmake, fetchcontent

I have the following directory structure for my cmake project (it is a minimally working example for the sake of this post). I am using `nlohmann_json` library for my project. I can create `jsonExample1` and can successfully run `jsonExample1.exe` but having difficulty building `jsonExample2` as Cmake complains about not being able to find `#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>`. Both `jsonExample1` and `jsonExample2` have the same file content for their source files.

Could someone kindly let me know what I am missing that is preventing `jsonExample2` from being built? I want to be able to build `jsonExample2` from the top level `CMakeLists.txt` (is this not recommended? In my actual project, I will be builing a library that uses `nlohmann` for the main executable of the project).

```
myapp
│
│ CMakeLists.txt
│
├───example
│ CMakeLists.txt
│ json.example.cpp
│
├───external
│   └───nlohmann_json
│           CMakeLists.txt
│
└───src
  json.example.cpp
```

The content of the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(my-app VERSION 1.0.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
add_subdirectory(external/nlohmann_json)
add_subdirectory(example) # it contains jsonExample1
add_executable(jsonExample2)
set_target_properties(jsonExample2 PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
target_sources(jsonExample2 PRIVATE src/json.example.cpp)
target_link_directories(jsonExample2 PRIVATE nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json)
```

The content of the top-level `/external/nlohmann_json/CMakeLists.txt` is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(libjson VERSION 1.0.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(nlohmann_json GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/nlohmann/json.git)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(nlohmann_json)
```

The content of the top-level `/example/CMakeLists.txt` is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(projExamples VERSION 1.0.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
add_executable(jsonExample1 json.example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(jsonExample1 PRIVATE nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json)
```

The content of `src/json.example.cpp` and `example/jsonExample1.cpp` are the same and is as follows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
using json = nlohmann::json;
int main() {
  json j = "{ \"happy\": true, \"pi\": 3.141 }"_json;
  std::string s = j.dump();
  std::cout << s;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `target_link_directories` it should be `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: That fixed the problem. Thank you very much.